# How to disable indentation in particular section in LaTeX?

Tags: latex, indentation

I need to disable indentation in only one section of my document (subsection, to be specific). How can I do that?

Default indentation is provided by indentfirst package.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It depends on how pervasively you want to eradicate the indentation.  But the first thing I'd try is setting `\parindent` to `0pt`:

```
Some text with normal indentation...

{\parindent0pt % disables indentation for all the text between { and }

Text with no indentation.

Still no indentation.

}% restore indentation

Indented again.
```

Comment: I think in LaTeX you really should be using `\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}` instead. `\parindent0pt` is pure TeX and its use may confuse LaTeX.

Comment: @Nikratio: It won't confuse LaTeX, but you can use \setlength as you say.

Comment: @David `\noindent` would only work for the first paragraph. The following paragraphs would have their usual indentation.

Comment: I just want to avoid indenting my \subsubsection. If I try `{\parindent0pt \subsubsection{Title}}`, the section head just disappears.

Comment: @CGFoX same happens with my intend. Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 14):

An environment that sets the indent could be a possible solution? You define it in the preamble like:

```
\newlength\mystoreparindent
\newenvironment{myparindent}[1]{%
\setlength{\mystoreparindent}{\the\parindent}
\setlength{\parindent}{#1}
}{%
\setlength{\parindent}{\mystoreparindent}
}
```

In your document you would then write something like:

```
\begin{myparindent}{0pt}
This paragraph is not indented, ehm well, actually it is indented by 0pt
which is the same as not indented.

And this paragraph neither\ldots
\end{myparindent}
```

Or if you want a large paragraph indent

```
\begin{myparindent}{5cm}
The first line of this paragraph is indented by 5 cm.

And so is the first line of the next paragraph.
\end{myparindent}
```

Comment: Why do you think question with already accepted answer since 2010 needs another answer?

Comment: @Michał: This is useful if you want to use an environment.

Answer (score 4):

\noindent I think is what you want.

Comment: \noindent disables indentation only in one paragraph.